# check if button is active or not in controller

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i have a single toggle button that changes color when clicked active. but now i'm stuck as to how i'll get the value of the button (active or inactive) in my controller. how should i approach this?

here's the error code:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'clicked' of undefined
```

here's the html code:

```
<button class="button button-clear icon ion-star button-energized" ng-model="singleTog" ng-click="toggleButton(item.name)" ng-class="singleTog.clicked?'button-energized':'button-dark'" ></button>
```

and here's the controller.js code:

```
$scope.toggleButton = function(candidateName)
{
  $scope.singleTog.clicked=!$scope.singleTog.clicked
  if($scope.singleTog.clicked==true)
  {
    if(favoriteList.indexOf(candidateName) == -1) //does not exist in array
    {
        $scope.numbers.push(candidateName);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    if(favoriteList.indexOf(candidateName) != -1) //exists in array
    {
        var index = $scope.favoriteList.indexOf(candidateName);
        $scope.favoriteList.splice(index, 1);   
    }
  }

    alert('favorites = ' + favoriteList);
}
```

Comment: Try to define default state `$scope.singleTog = {}`, before `$scope.toggleButton`

Comment: Where do you initialize your $scope.singleTog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define an emty object as `$scope.singleTog = {}`

Try this

```
$scope.singleTog = {}
$scope.toggleButton = function(candidateName)
{
  $scope.singleTog.clicked=!$scope.singleTog.clicked
  if($scope.singleTog.clicked==true)
  {
    if(favoriteList.indexOf(candidateName) == -1) //does not exist in array
    {
        $scope.numbers.push(candidateName);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    if(favoriteList.indexOf(candidateName) != -1) //exists in array
    {
        var index = $scope.favoriteList.indexOf(candidateName);
        $scope.favoriteList.splice(index, 1);   
    }
  }

    alert('favorites = ' + favoriteList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the color of the button when it is active or inactive you can use ng-class for that:

```
ng-class="$variableToEvaluate ? 'class-if-true' : 'class-if-false'"
```